# How can I exclude a file from g++ compiler options

Tags: makefile, g++, compiler-warnings

I'd like to compile most of my code with -Wconversion -Werror.

The problem is that I use a .cpp file that is open source and should not be modified, and compiling it with those flags fails because that specific .cpp file has issues with some "implicit conversions that may alter a value".

Can I somehow instruct the build to compile all other files with -Wconversion -Werror but compile that file without those flags?

Comment: Certainly `make` can be told to use different options to compile source into object files, and then to link the object files into an executable with as much specification as you care to demand.  Are you looking for an example, or a tailored approach to your situation?

Comment: While I'm composing my thoughts, here's the [GNU tutorial on `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) for future reference.

Comment: The "simple makefile" in the above linked tutorial avoids any "general" rule for making object files and spells out the compiler "recipe" for each such file.  So short answer is to have a special rule for the special source file, followed by a wildcard driven recipe for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `make` utility provides a rich set of facilities for customizing builds and for defaulting to implicit procedures for things that are routine logic.  The [GNU `make` tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) is a good starting point if there's a question related to the gcc toolchain.

Essentially a makefile contains the custom logic for building a project.  Rules consist of an apparent *target* separated from the *dependencies* by a colon on one line, and then (possibly zero or many) *recipes* on succeeding lines indented by a tab character that explain steps in building that *target*.  Bogus targets, eg. `clean`, may also be defined for convenience in maintaining a project.

If there's a target-specific rule, that will be used in preference to any implicit rule to build that target.  Probably the OP only needs to add a target-specific rule to an existing makefile that will govern the use of compiler options (building the object from the source).

Comment: The only downside is an annoying error from GNU Make. For example in one of my projects I get "warning: overriding recipe for target `unit-tests/tests-a-main.cpp'
" but this is not a show-stopper.